# PhoneGap displaying buffer in terminal

Tags: cordova, hybrid-mobile-app, phonegap-cli

I'm on Ubuntu 14.04 and using node 6.2.1. Now most of the time when I execute any command using phonegap, such as `phonegap platform add android` the output comes something like this:

```
<Buffer 41 64 64 69 6e 67 20 61 6e 64 72 6f 69 64 20 70 72 6f 6a 65 63 74 2e 2e 2e>
<Buffer 0a>
<Buffer 43 72 65 61 74 69 6e 67 20 43 6f 72 64 6f 76 61 20 70 72 6f 6a 65 63 74 20 66 6f 72 20 74 68 65 20 41 6e 64 72 6f 69 64 20 70 6c 61 74 66 6f 72 6d 3a>
<Buffer 0a 09 50 61 74 68 3a 20 70 6c 61 74 66 6f 72 6d 73 2f 61 6e 64 72 6f 69 64 0a 09 50 61 63 6b 61 67 65 3a 20 6e 65 74 2e 61 73 70 72 6f 76 2e 66 6c 61 ... >
<Buffer 0a>
<Buffer 09 4e 61 6d 65 3a 20 41 73 70 72 6f 76 5f 46 6c 61 73 68 6c 69 67 68 74 0a>
<Buffer 09 41 63 74 69 76 69 74 79 3a 20 4d 61 69 6e 41 63 74 69 76 69 74 79 0a 09 41 6e 64 72 6f 69 64 20 74 61 72 67 65 74 3a 20 61 6e 64 72 6f 69 64 2d 32 ... >
<Buffer 41 6e 64 72 6f 69 64 20 70 72 6f 6a 65 63 74 20 63 72 65 61 74 65 64 20 77 69 74 68 20 63 6f 72 64 6f 76 61 2d 61 6e 64 72 6f 69 64 40 35 2e 31 2e 31>
<Buffer 0a>
```

Now when I execute the same command with cordova on same folder like `cordova platform add android`, it shows me the correct outputs. Is there anything wrong with my setup? Is there anyone else facing the same problem like this? Please let me know if there is any way I can fix this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this issue](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-cli/issues/603) there was a bug that was fixed yesterday and the package wasn't updated at npm yet, so you should update phonegap within github with latest merges

```
sudo npm install -g  git+https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-cli.git
```